# Display image on top of bootstrap <nav>

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a JSFiddle set up here showing what is currently happening: http://jsfiddle.net/YX7T6/1/

This is the code:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li>
                CText
            </li>
        </ul>

        <div class="pull-right">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg"> button1 </button>
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg"> button2 </button>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <a href="#">
        <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/150/150" class="img-thumbnail" style="margin-top:-130px">
    </a>
</div>
```

I'm trying to get the image to show on top of the navigation not behind it as it is now. I've tried changing the z-index of the image to something higher but nothing has changed. What should I try next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the other answers mentioned, `z-index` only works on elements that have `position`. Applying z-index to an element that has no position will simply be ignored.

```
img { 
  position: relative; 
  z-index: 1;
}
```

Will make the browser recognize the z-index attribute, and place the image above the nav menu. In the future whenever you're having issues with z-index not being recognized, the first thing you should do is check whether the elements in question have position.

However, in this specific case, rather than messing with negative margins, it may be simpler to do:

```
img { 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `position` like `position:relative;` to your element
if you plan to control it's `z-index` property

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YX7T6/3/)

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, use `position: absolute` on the `img` and skip the `z-index` stuff.

http://jsfiddle.net/YX7T6/8/